# Is it appropriate to put "since" at the beginning of a sentence if it comes after a question?

Tags: questions, commas, since

> What do you usually do during that period? Since I have no idea what I’ll do.

Normally, I would put a comma before "since", but since the first part is a question, I have to end the sentence there and start a new one, right? What if I put them both together?

> What do you usually do during that period, since I have no idea what I'll do?

Would that be correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first quoted sentence is grammatically incorrect, because it combines two independent clauses without proper punctuation or a coordinating conjunction. Here's a breakdown of the sentence:

1. "What do you usually do during that period?" - This is an
   interrogative sentence asking about someone's activities during a
   specific time frame. It is grammatically correct on its own.
2. "Since I have no idea what I’ll do." - This is a dependent clause
   that provides a reason for asking the question in the first
   sentence. However, it cannot stand alone as a sentence, and it
   should be connected to the main clause with a comma, not a period.

To make the sentence grammatically correct, you can combine the two clauses using a comma:

"What do you usually do during that period, since I have no idea what I’ll do?"

Thus, your second sentence correct.

Comment: Okay. As soon as I typed that second sentence, I felt like I had heard it somewhere, heard it said, but I guess I've never read a sentence like that before. I guess I could also drop the "since" and just put *What do you usually do during that period? I have no idea what I’ll do.* Two separate sentences

Comment: That is possible, but since the two sentences are logically connected, and the 2nd sentence pretty much "extends" the 1st one, I wouldn't suggest separating them. But yes, what you did is also perfectly valid.

Comment: Don't you think the use of **will** here is rather odd?  It really doesn't sound natural to me. I think it should perhaps be **could/should**, since the speaker is uncertain about what to do.

Comment: @BillyKerr using "should" or "could" would convey the idea that something needs to be done about something. You are right that it might be more appropriate to use these words, but we would need to know the context. For example, if it's just casual speech, and the person is trying to think of what he/she will do in his/her upcoming free time, "will" would be appropriate. Using "will" in this sentence is grammatically valid.

Comment: @BillyKerr I think I am going to take your suggestion and change it to "should". The speaker was originally just trying to decide what she should do that afternoon, but I think I will change it so that she is trying to decide what she'll be doing every day at that time from now on.